# CSS Positioning, need help for alignment of links

Tags: css, alignment, positioning

**in all catelog pages of site the link menu on top is not getting aligned**, see sample link - [car finance](http://www.mycarhelpline.com/index.php?option=com_forms&view=pages&layout=finance&Itemid=6) section.

*whenever we try to put 3rd link on top menu left- it splits to next line

Same issue on top menu right - any 4th link splits to next line*

We tried changing width - used all permutation / combination - but to no help

**What we seek for it is**

- .footer-top-box-left - for top menu link units
- .footer-top-box-right - for google custom search box

so that both comes in 1 single line

below is the code of css used for - pl suggest

```css
#footer-container { 
   float:left;
   width:1000px;
   clear:both;
   background:#FFFFFF;
   text-align:center !important;
}   

#footer-container .footer-top-box {
   float:left;
   width:965px;
   margin:0 0 10px 5px;
   padding:0 5px 0 10px;
   height:33px;
   background:url(../images/footer-box-bg.gif) repeat-x;
   border:1px solid #e7e5e5;
}    

.footer-top-box .footer-top-box-left {
   float:left;
   width:300px;
   margin:0 0 0 5px;
   font: normal 10px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   color:#000000;
   text-align:left;
   padding:10px 0 0 0
}    

.footer-top-box-left img {
   margin:0 3px 0 3px;
}    

.footer-top-box .footer-top-box-right {
   float:right;
   width:500px;
   margin:0 5px 0 0 ;
   font: normal 10px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   color:#000000;
   text-align:right;
   padding:10px 0 0 0;
}    

.footer-top-box-right p {

margin:0;
padding:0;
font: normal 10px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#000000;
}    

.footer-top-box-right p a:link,
.footer-top-box-right p a:hover,
.footer-top-box-right p a:visited { 
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   font: normal 10px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   color:#b60205;
   text-decoration:underline;
   text-align:justify;
}
```

Comment: If you indent text four spaces it will be formatted as code, greatly improving readability. In addition, you'll get better responses if you make the example more minimal (e.g. the particular fonts and colors aren't relevant to the example).

Answer (score 1):

Change the width of the holder div - "footer-top-box-left" or "footer-top-box-right" and it should work.

Testing with a copy of your html I was able to add a 3rd item on the left after changing "footer-top-box-left" from 300px to 400px width.

If you want to have box boxes as a single line I would recommend making a single div and perhaps using float: right for the menu items that must be aligned to the right.